# Access the list of SIM mobile numbers installed in the iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, core-telephony

Can I get list of all sim installed in my iPhone including eSim
and get its number ?

I have requirement in which I need at the time of registration , at user mobile number, user installed sim numbers list shows for dropdown.

Any way to solve it?
Is apple allowed it ?
If yes please suggest code at swift language.
I tried to detect SIM but not getting sim phone number list.

```
import UIKit
import CoreTelephony

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        listSIMCardDetails()
    }
    
    func listSIMCardDetails() {
        let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
        if let subscriber = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider {
            print("Carrier Name: \(subscriber.carrierName ?? "Unknown")")
            print("Mobile Country Code (MCC): \(subscriber.mobileCountryCode ?? "Unknown")")
            print("Mobile Network Code (MNC): \(subscriber.mobileNetworkCode ?? "Unknown")")
            print("ISO Country Code: \(subscriber.isoCountryCode ?? "Unknown")")
            print("Allows VOIP: \(subscriber.allowsVOIP)")
        } else {
            print("No SIM Card Detected")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely not.  It would be a privacy violation if apps could access this information. Note also that all of the properties you are accessing are deprecated after iOS 16.0 and cannot be relied upon.

Comment: Any posible solution?

Comment: No.  If you want the user's phone number you will need to ask them to enter it.

Comment: how to make it SIM card authentication ? https://developer.tru.id/tutorials/ios-sim-card-mobile-auth
How it work?

Comment: That product seems to rely on an integration with the mobile network operator. If the user is using a supported MNO, then a data request is made from the device to a URL in the MNO network. The MNO can then return information about the subscriber.